# Редакция вопросов и ответов. Вертикальное или горизонтальное

Tags: предложение, дизайн

Интересно мнение сообщества по поводу расположения окна редактирования вопроса/ответа и его представления на выходе. В данный момент оно вертикальное. Не скажу, что преуспел сильно в количестве и качестве своих вопросов и ответов, но бывает временами неудобно и редактировать и крутить scroll страницы вниз, чтобы посмотреть на представление. Особенно когда ответ или вопрос не в 5-10 строк.

Предложение. Разместить WYSIWYG (окно редактирования) и окно представления горизонтально. Одно слева, другое справа. Синхронное отображение. По моему будет очень удобно. Возможно, реализовать такое не так сложно.

Comment: [Подобное предложение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70703/339911) было озвучено уже почти аж 7 (семь!) лет назад.

Comment: для вопросов есть Stylish))) в принципе для ответов тоже.... но для ответов можно воспользоваться расширением для браузера от одного человека https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31646705#31646705

Comment: Есть расширения, позволяющие вынести редактирование в отдельный внешний редактор, который можно разместить где угодно: [GhostText](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText) (Sublime, Atom, VSC, Vim <-> Chrome, Firefox) и [Atomic Chrome](https://github.com/tuvistavie/atomic-chrome) (Atom, Emacs <-> Chrome, Firefox).

Comment: Угу, приходится часто жать F11, чтобы получить ещё чуть-чуть вертикального пространства. А тут ещё эту панель сверху прилепили :(.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov панель можно отлепить в настройках. И монитор в портретный режим повернуть :)

Comment: @D-side мне почему-то кажется, что % любителей подобных расширений крайне низок. Вот если бы готовый функционал из коробки...

Comment: @alexolut встроенный Vim или Emacs? В смысле, какой из двух?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, можно повернуть монитор вертикально

Comment: Я праивльно понимаю, что нет и не будет встроенной возможности разделения экрана редактора горизонтально или вертикально по выбору и надо плагины скачивать?))